# How do I use the on board oscillator?

Tags: vhdl, programmable-logic

I have the MAX II EPM240 CPLD Minimal Development Board which has an on-board 50 MHz oscillator. According to the "EPM240MAINBOARD Schematic Diagram" [file](https://www.openimpulse.com/blog/products-page/product-category/max-ii-epm240-cpld-minimal-development-board/), the output of the oscillator goes to PIN 63, but there is no PIN 63 on the board. How do I use it? What modifications should I make to my VHDL file to enable it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This "minimal development board" is set up as a barebones breakout for the CPLD, the clock is already directly connected to the CPLD, its up to you to use that CLK in for your purposes

Most of the pins are wired directly to the MAXII, Pin 64 is the GCLK3 pin on the Max II

Pin 64 is seen on the left of the screenshot in component `U1B` (which is one bank of the CPLD pins) It is also connected to Pin 34 on Header P2 as seen in the screenshot below it.

[image]
[image]

To use it you have design your core to use PIN64 (using TQFP numbering) which is named IO_GLK3 in your CPLD definition

[image]